# Is there any speed difference if I use UMat and turn off GPU processing in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

Assume that I have a code which is written in C++ and uses Mat to hold images.

I want to change all Mats to UMat so the application runs on GPU as well on CPU (If I turn off GPU processing by calling ocl::setUseOpenCL(false);)

But I am wondering if I do this, is there any performance changes?

so in summery, if I have a code that uses Mat, if I change all Mats to UMats, is there any performance difference (When not running on GPU)?

## Edit1

to clear the scope of question, Let me reword it:

why should not I use uMat instead of Mat assuming I am not using GPU?

Comment: Measure in your case then measure again. There are too many factors to consider: data transferring to/from GPU, how many operations you perform (overhead is higher for GPU)  and so on. Also without GPU consider that compilers will optimize your code very deeply...IMO if you get a _single generic_  answer then you may safely ignore it, AFAIK there is not The Answer.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for your comment. Please note I am not looking at how my code would work on GPU if I am using OpenCL, but what I am looking is that If I have NO GPU, what would happen if I use UMat instead of Mat? So in other word: why should not I use UMat everywhere that I am using Mat?

Comment: Difference (in performance) between Mat and UMat (without GPU support) IMO shouldn't be even measurable: without GPU _old_ code will be executed (assuming _typical_ pattern is to prepare data, perform some calculation and then call a time consuming OpenCV function). Of course this is a _reasoning_, to have an _answer_ the only way is to measure. This is for _drop-in_ case. If you'll **optimize your code for GPU scenario** then you'll have higher performance gain but it _may_ affect CPU only performance.

Answer (score 0):

When using UMat, opencv utilises Transparent API to use additional hardware attached. So, by turning off GPU processing you shouldn't expect a speedup.

Comment: I know that If I turn of GPU processing, I am not gaining anything, but my question is , Do I lose speed?